# Trying to mirror a volume

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, mirroring

I originally had my HD mirrored to another one, but then it said the plex was missing, so I took it out and checked it and it was dead.
So i bought a 2TB SSHD to replace it.
But now it's not letting me mirror it, coming up with this error:
"All disks holding extents for a given volume must have the same sector size, and the sector size must be valid."
So I checked the sector sizes:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo C:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        ******************
NTFS Version   :                   3.1
LFS Version    :                   2.0
Number Sectors :                   0x000000006dd1f7ff
Total Clusters :                   0x000000000dba3eff
Free Clusters  :                   0x00000000058d9d1a
Total Reserved :                   0x0000000000001a20
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        512
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            0x0000000042780000
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000b18af
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x000000000635cac0
Mft Zone End   :                   0x000000000635f580
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     0
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0x0
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :     64C30149-2EFA-11E4-BECE-806E6F6E6963

C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo D:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       *****************
NTFS Version   :                   3.1
LFS Version    :                   2.0
Number Sectors :                   0x0000000071b5afff
Total Clusters :                   0x000000000e36b5ff
Free Clusters  :                   0x000000000e35e9d8
Total Reserved :                   0x0000000000000000
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        512
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            0x0000000000040000
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft Zone End   :                   0x00000000000cc820
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     0
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0x0
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :     311FCD06-2FD2-11E6-BF24-D43D7E4E2CEE
```

And the physical sector sizes are both the same, so I don't understand why it's not letting me do it.
The other disk is a 1TB SSD and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Ever find the solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered similar problem last night and it took me an hour to find the solution. Short answer: the information given by `fsutil` might not be accurate.

My home server is running Server 2012R2 on an Intel 320 SSD. I wanted to mirror the drive with a new bought Intel S3500 SSD. Same error occurred and `fsutil` told me the physical sector size of the two drives are both 512 bytes. `MSInfo` and `chkdsk` reported 512-byte sector size as well.

I downloaded Intel SSD Data Center Tool and it told me a different story: the S3500 drive had a physical sector size of 4096 bytes. I toggled the sector size to 512 bytes with the same tool and restarted the computer. Problem solved.
I also did a benchmark with HDTune Pro and didn't find any significant gain or loss in terms of random read performance before and after the switch.

Comment: Can't even seem to convert the OS disk from basic to dynamic as you need to do that for mirroring, just says isn't enough free space on disk management, so I tried Aomei Dynamic Disk Manager, and that came up with an error 39, which says its something to do with encrypted files, but I don't use bitlocker, so I'm confused.